# C++ reference and pointer relationship

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, relationship

Sorry for the noob question, I'm just a little confused by the relationship between pointer and reference in C++.

Which of the following actions is(are) legal in C++?

- Pointer to Pointer;
- Pointer to Reference;
- Reference to Pointer;
- Reference to Reference;

I know pointer to pointer is totally legal, i.e.:

```
int* p;
*p = 5;
int ** pp;
*pp = p;
```

(I don't know if I'm doing the right thing.)

Could someone clarify these for me with some non-trivial examples?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pointer to Pointer:**

Your example that showcased pointer-to-pointer was semantically correct, save for the fact that you didn't allocate memory for `p`.

**Pointer to Reference:**

There is no such thing.

**Reference to Pointer:**

References to pointers act in the same way as references to non-pointers. They allow the aliasing of an object through another object. For example:

```
int *p = new int;
int *& ref = p;

ref = new int(5);

std::cout << *p; // 5
```

They also facilitate passing a pointer as a mutable parameter. In C, one would send the address of the pointer to the function if it were meant to be changed:

```
void f(int **ptr)
{
    *ptr = new int(10);
}

int *p;
f(&p);
```

In C++, we can simply use a reference to pointer so this is not explicitly needed:

```
void f(int *&ptr)
{
    ptr = new int(10);
}

int *p;
f(p);
```

**Reference to Reference:**

There is no such thing. Are you thinking about `T&&`? That is an rvalue-reference, an important aspect of [move-semantics](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html).

Comment: could you repost the link? 404.. :)

Comment: Your reference-less pointer example (the second one) is flawed, it's neither C, nor does it modify the function argument.

Comment: @EmmaWang I've change the link to [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html)

Answer (score 4):

> the relationship between pointer and reference in C++

None. There's no relationship. They're completely different.

> Which of the following actions is(are) legal in C++?

Pointer to pointer and reference to pointer. Pointer to reference and reference to reference do not exist.

> (I don't know if I'm doing the right thing.)

You aren't: the snippet you posted invokes undefined behavior (as-is) because you are dereferencing uninitialized pointers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry I don't know the exact word to describe my question..

Comment: I'm trying to get some non-trivial examples as I said in my question. That's why I didn't choose your answer, but it's useful answer to others apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You can have:

- A pointer to pointer: `int** i`
- A reference to pointer: `int* &i`

You can't have:

- A pointer to reference
- A reference to reference

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is trying to understand what the basic concepts are. A *pointer* is a variable that holds the address of another object. A *reference* is an alias to another object, that is, creates a new name for an existing object.

The most important thing here is that after initialization of a reference, the name refers to the real object and not to the reference.

With that in mind,

> can you have a pointer to a pointer?

Yes, the pointer is a variable that holds an address. A different pointer might hold the address of this first pointer.

> can you have a reference to a reference? i.e. can you have an alias to
>   an alias?

No, the alias represents the real object that lives somewhere else by another name. You can create new aliases that refer to the same object but you cannot create an alias to an alias.

> can you have a reference to a pointer? i.e. can you alias a pointer?

Yes, you can refer to a variable of pointer type. The fact that the variable holds an object of type pointer or of type int won't matter, it is a variable and you can create an alias.

> can you create a pointer to a reference? i.e. can you create a pointer to an alias?

No, an alias is just another name for just one variable, you can have a pointer to the original variable, and to obtain it you can use either the original name or an alias, but you cannot have a pointer to an alias.